# Can I travel to Europe with indefinite leave to enter the UK?

Tags: schengen-visas, finland, uk-residents

Can I travel to Finland with a UK visa residence (indefinite leave to enter the UK), or do I need to get the Schengen visa for me to able to travel to Finland?

Comment: What's your citizenship? Also do you have an EU spouse?

Answer (score 2):

**No**. You need a visa for Finland. UK ILR does not allow visa free travel to the rest of Europe on its own.

Comment: ILR might make it more lightly to get that visa, but many other factors affect the probability.